# LIST DESCRIPTION NOT WORKING WITH DICTIONARY (PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

```
#python
pets=[] #created an empty list 

d={'owner_name': 'holland',
     'pet_kind':'mischieveous',
  }


d={'owner_name': 'rowman',
       'pet_kind':'smart',
  }


d={'owner_name': 'clark',
         'pet_kind':'happy'
  }

d={'owner_name': 'shaun',
             'pet_kind':'shy',
  }

d={'owner_name': 'seaman',
         'pet_kind':'intellectual',
  }

pets=[pets.append(pet) for pet in d.items()] 

print(pets)
```

output is showing [None, None] , I believe it should show the dictionary #appended in pets but it is not please help a newbie here .. please

```
for pet in d.items():
    pets.append(pet)
print(pets)
```

also if i use the for loop the second way it still gives me only the last dictionary as answer, the seaman and intellectual one, i am hopeful to learn this lang please help
here i have included the second way above please check

Comment: Kindly refrain from writing ALL CAPS. That doesn't make anything clearer.

Comment: Quite frankly, there’s so much wrong here, it’s hard to know where to start…

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? Is this just homework?
You can simply create a list of dicts to get the same result:

```
pets = [{'owner_name': 'holland', 'pet_kind':'mischieveous'},
{'owner_name': 'rowman', 'pet_kind':'smart'},
{'owner_name': 'clark', 'pet_kind':'happy'},
{'owner_name': 'shaun', 'pet_kind':'shy'},
{'owner_name': 'seaman', 'pet_kind':'intellectual'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code would do the work:

```
d = {
"owner_name": "seaman",
"pet_kind": "intellectual",
}

pets=[pet for pet in d.items()]

print(pets)
```

the second way you said has a problem that is because you named all your variables "d". they overwrite each other.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, the list comprehension:

  ```
  pets = [pets.append(pet) for pet in d.items()]
  ```

  This syntax collects the results of the method call `pets.append(...)` in a list, then assigns it to the variable `pets`. However, `pets.append(...)` does not return anything — it modifies the list in place — so that will collect a list of `None` values as returned from each call of the method.

  The method will append it to `pets` in-place, but then the assignment operator will overwrite `pets` with the list of `None` values, which you're seeing.
- Secondly, the assignments:

  ```
  d = {
      'owner_name': 'holland',
      'pet_kind': 'mischievous',
  }


  d = {
      'owner_name': 'rowman',
      'pet_kind': 'smart',
  }

  ...
  ```

  These will assign different values to the same variable `d`, just like writing:

  ```
  x = 1
  x = 2
  ...
  ```
- Finally, the `.items()` method

  ```
  for pet in d.items():
  ```

  This method is applicable to a dictionary, not a list; it turns that dictionary into a list of pairs, so within the loop, the variable `pet` will have the value `('owner_name', 'seaman')` the first time through the loop and then `('pet_kind', 'intellectual')` the second time through the loop.

  As a side-note, it's often more convenient to "unpack" those pairs into a pair of variables, like this:

  ```
  for key, value in d.items():
  ```